# application pool identity change

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-7

I've got a web method set up on SERVER A and need to connect to the file system on SERVER B.

Currently I have a wide array of web services that already run on SERVER A where the identity on the application pool is set to NETWORK SERVICE.  The issue is that I cannot seem to give the NETWORK SERVICE on A access to the file system on B.  Changing the user on the app pool isn't really an option as there are too many possible train wrecks that could materialize on the outgoing web service calls.

So the solution I am trying to come up with is temporarily changing the Web Method identity user from NETWORK SERVICE  to DOMAIN/SOMEUSER when the web method is called.

The property I need to change is System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Can anyone tell me how I can go about doing this?  Many of the solutions online seem to refer to Windows Azure - which I'm not using, so the approaches outlined don't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to play with the  tag in the web.config. Our is normally set to `<identity impersonate="false" />` and the application pool uses a domain user for permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by play with the web config?  I am trying to get a user set at the method level.  I don't want to have to make the change global.

Comment: Be sure to restrict your domain user permissions if you are changing the application pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using impersonate in your service.

```
<system.web> ....
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

Comment: Using identity impersonate works but again, it's global. Is there a way of limiting which web methods use it?

Comment: You could impersonate a method in code, but i wouldn't recommend it for a web service.  [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158).

Comment: Or if you use WCF you can also choose witch method use impersonate.

Comment: Finally i think that You should host your web methods into 2 separates service.

Comment: Thanks Guish... I'm lookinginto WCF.  But I like your second suggestion.  That would really simplify this!  :-)